# Matlab integral3 - function to be integrated contains an integral function

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm finding it a little tricky to explain my problem so please bear with me. I am trying to solve an integro-differential equation using an iterative procedure. This procedure means that from the first iteration I can find my required function as a three dimensional integral with the argument of the function as the upper limit of the outer integral.

I then need to substitute this function back into the integral again, but when I do this I get the error

> Error using integral3 (line 66) 
>   XMAX must be a floating point scalar.

My code is given below. I have tried using the symbolic integration, but my integrand is far to complicated for that.

```
err = 1;
g = @(q) 1;
a = 3;
xmin = 0.2;
xmax = @(x) x;
ymin = 0.1;
ymax = @(x) x;
zmin = @(x,y) x-y;
zmax = @(x,y) x+y;

while err>0.1
    e = g(10);
    G = @(x,y,z) ((z.^2+x.^2-y.^2).^2)./(z.^2.*y.^2.*x.^2).*sqrt(2.*(y.^2.*x.^2+y.^2.*z.^2+x.^2.*z.^2)-y.^4-x.^4-z.^4).*x.^(a-1).*y.^(-a).*g(y).*(z.^(-a).*g(z)-x.^(-a).*g(x));
    g = @(q) 1 + (a-4)/(8).*integral3(G,0.2,q,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax,'Method','iterated','AbsTol',1e-1,'RelTol',1e-1);
    err = abs(g(10)-e)
end
```

Comment: You've made `xmax`, `ymax`, `zmin` and `zmax` functions of `x` and `y`, but when you use them in `integral3` you haven't given them any inputs.

Comment: Is that not allowed in this case? Since I do not want to specify real number limits rather I want z in terms of x and y, and y in terms of x, while the specified integral is over the x values which in this case is the argument of the function g. In the example here, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral3.html, they do not give arguments to the limits so I believe I do not have to in my case either. I will add that if I let `q` be a real number rather than a variable then everything works fine (albeit slowly), however I really do require the upper limit to be a variable.

Comment: Then make `g` a function of `q`, `x`, `y` and `z`. You have to somehow tell `integral3` where to integrate, which you currently are not.